# The type or namespace name 'HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting this error when trying to publish my project

> The type or namespace name 'HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling `HtmlAgiltyPack`, and to install an earlier version. nothing seems to change that. I can see `HtmlAgilityPack` in the `References` folder. What am I missing?

### EDIT

Added screenshot of the error
[image: Screen shot of the error]

Comment: Is the project development platform same as deployment platform? Any changes such as "Any CPU" to "x86" are present?

Comment: @Ozan Gunceler I'm not sure if I understand, I'm develop it on my local machine and publish it to Azure. The platform target is set to "Any CPU"

Comment: Any CPU should be fine. When you say you installed agility pack, are you using Nuget to do this or through an offline installer?

Comment: Nuget, I've updated it to the lasted version, tested everything locally, tried to publish, got this error , then went back to previous version.

Comment: Let me try... Will get back to you shortly

Answer (score 1):

I made a test on my local and publish the app to Azure without any issues. Maybe following steps will help you to identify the issue on your side.

Create an empty ASP.NET project.

[image]

[image]

Install HtmlAgilityPack from Nuget

[image]

Publish to Azure

[image]

[image]

Test with Browser

[image]

My HtmlAgilityPack reference has the following properties;

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference properties and ensure "copy local" is set to true or always

Comment: Checked, it's set to true

Answer (score 0):

If HtmlAgilityPack is in the references folder then you are probably not using the `using` statement. The correct using statement that includes HtmlAgilityPack is:`using HtmlAgilityPack;`. If that is not at the top of your file along with the other using statements then you can try restoring the nuget packages that you have in your project.

Comment: I double checked that, that website works fine locally, I get this error only when I'm trying to publish

Comment: Are you getting the error when you publish it or when you are operating your app on a web server

Comment: when I try to publish it

Answer (score 0):

We frequently have issues with Nuget claiming to have installed a package successfully, but then when the code is run we get an error that the reference cannot be found. What I've found will work in this case:

1. Find the downloaded dll file that Nuget installed.
2. Copy the entire folder to a public location on the server
3. Add a script task that will run prior to the script task the error occurs in to set the reference:

   ```
       public void Main()
   {
       // putting in a wrapper to load assembly "manually"
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
   }
   static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   {
       if (args.Name.Contains("<name of lost reference>"))
       {
           string path = @"<your location here>";
           return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "<the errant dll"));
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```